# ubuntu backup, upgrade ubuntu and then restore

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) as a wubi installation in my laptop. i.e inside windows, in a drive. Now I need to move to another laptop. I found instructions for backing up in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Now as a rule I will be getting a new laptop with Windows again I need to use wubi. So in my new system I want to try 11.10 instead of 11.04

So my question is if I create a backup of 11.04 and in my new laptop if I upgrade to 11.10, can I restore it back in 11.10?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this question does not belong here.

Comment: This question is probably best suited for the [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com) StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded and then backedup and now it works